# How do I compare code from before and after a git pull?

Tags: git, github

Here's my situation: I've been on holiday and so someone else has been working on my git feature branch. I've come back and pulled the branch to get the updates from my colleague.

What I'm wondering is how do I get a side-by-side comparison of what code has been updated? I can checkout my code from before but this doesn't explicitly show me all the changes. How do I only see specifically what has changed?

Ideally, I'd like to do this in a prettier way than `git diff HEAD@{1}` which doesn't give me any syntax highlighting in my terminal.

Comment: If you use `git fetch` instead of `git pull`, you can compare your local branch with the tracking branch before performing the actual merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a GUI, you can set more comfortable diff tools to be fired up upon `git difftool` if you configure them accordingly beforehand. Take a look here : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool

```
# example of setting line for using Beyond Compare as a diff tool
config --global diff.tool bc

# then to use it just use difftool instead of diff
git difftool HEAD@{1}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the short SHA of your last commit via `$ git log` or your company's BitBucket/GitLab/whatever.

   Let's assume it's `ef0acc2`.
2. Use Git's `difftool` command to show the differences between your last commit and `HEAD`:

   ```
   $ git difftool ef0acc2 HEAD
   ```

   If you don't like the default diff tool you can tell Git which one to choose with:

   ```
   $ git difftool --tool vimdiff ef0acc2 HEAD
   ```

   where `vimdiff` could be any tool listed with:

   ```
   $ git difftool --tool-help
   ```

   Note that the diff tool is invoked sequentially, once for each file in the diff. Close it to see the next file's diff.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to compare git files across versions is to use some good IDE. The most popular which I am using is IntelliJ IDEA. You can download the community version and open your local git code in Intellij and can compare your files for previous versions. Dont forget to pull the latest code.

Here is the link if you want to read more :-
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/comparing-file-versions.html

Answer (score 0):

In GIT bash or command line is can't be prettier...

Try the following command, it's little different between `git diff`

```
git log -p -2
```

From your tag, it seems that you are using VS Code, you can see there the diff in a nice way, read [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol) article.

You can also see the code changes in a nice visualize way by use [Git GUI Clients](https://git-scm.com/download/gui/windows).

Answer (score 0):

You can compare easily & clearly using **Bitbucket** or **SourceTree** Atlassian tools. These tools provide GUI support. instead of trying with commands. Every code changes can be viewed in specific colors. (green : added new codes, pink : deleted codes)